# Method that gathers debug info about another Method

Tags: php, methods, reflection

I have a Method that does some jobs, something like this:

```
public function foo(array $ids)
{
    $foos = $this->getAllFoos($ids);
    $foos = $this->sortAllFoos($foos);
    $filteredFoos = $this->filterOutsomeFoo($foos);
    
    return $filteredFoos;
}
```

This method is used by the system. Now *actual people* want step by step insights on how we end up with the `$filteredFoo` so they can double check wether it's done right. I'm looking for a way to do this elegant.

- I make a copy of this method and store everything in seperate values, but that'll become a maintenance hell as I now need to make all changes twice, I dont like WET. I want DRY.
- I can pass an extra param like `foo(array $ids, &$debug = [])` and add a `$debug['ids']=$ids`, `$debug['foos']=$foos`, `$debug['sortedFoos']=$sortedFoos`, but as my actual method is a bit larger, that nearly doubles the lines in my method.

Does anyone know a more elegant solution (I'm currently using option 2) which can be used?

<sub>NB: In the debug version I can prettify stuff for display purposes, it doesn't need to be done in the fetching.</sub>